# Made sections with elements filtered by value in each with jinja

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, jinja2

i'm new to Python. I want to made different categories(regions) in which are displayed the cities with that region category name value. For now i have different sections filtered by region name, but the code is heavy because is calling n times the database for each region. I hope this is clear enough, i have made comments in the code to explain it better.

The two collection on mongodb are like :

Cities:

```
{
_id: id
city_name: name
city_region: region
}
```

Regions:

```
{
_id: id
region_name: region 
cities_in_region: city_name 
}
```

My python def code is:

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", cities=mongo.db.cities.find(), 
                        regions = mongo.db.regions.find(),
                        user_logged=user_logged)
```

I'm thinking to use a nested loop but it only show me the result for the first region, the other are empty.
I tried as well with groupby() but i always have the same problem, only the first section has elements, the others are empty.

```
{%for region in regions%} 
    #Should make a section for each region in regions and it does
    # but only the first section with the city_region == region_name is showed
    #the second section with the second region is empty
    <div>
        <p class="index_header">{{region.region_name}}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="row ">
            {%for city in cities if city.city_region == region.region_name%}
          #content here
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {%endfor%}
        </div>
    </div>
    {%endfor%}
```

I tried the following code as well but i still have the same error.

```
{%for region in regions%}
<h3>{{region.region_name}}</h3>
        {%for city in cities%}
        {% if region.region_name == city.city_region%}

        <h5>{{ city.city_name }}</h5>

        {%endif%}
        {%endfor%}
        {%endfor%}
```

At the moment as said only the region has elements in it, the other regions are empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey with a db I advise you to use [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) a well documented and easy to use Python framework which include a data base gesture and an administration.

If you have any other questions : don't hesitate to ask in comments below.

Otherwise you can put my answer as 'the best answer', I will really appreciate for the time I spend reading your code.

Comment: But is there a way to have this working without django?

Comment: Of course with an Ajax server and a MySQL server everything is possible, Nevertheless it will be more complicated to code and to debug because Flask was not created to use DB. That's why I advise you to use Django, which is basically a near framework (with the same html and a lot of other things are similar).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i will go more deep into python and learn Django, at the moment the project is working 100%  anyway, i want just to figure it out how to boost my app. I appreciate your help.